¿Cómo se traduciría al español "wait for the other shoe to drop"?
La expresión "wait for the other shoe to drop" significa:

To defer action or decision until another matter is finished or resolved.
To await a seemingly inevitable event, especially one that is not desirable.

¿Cómo se podría traducir al español?

Como siempre, todo dependerá del contexto a usar y del lugar o región
La traducción de ambas frases es:

Aplazar una acción o decisión hasta que se termine o resuelva otro asunto.


Esperar un acontecimiento aparentemente inevitable, especialmente uno que no es deseable.

Yo lo podría relacionar con:

La fruta madura cae sola.
A su tiempo maduran las uvas.
Dar tiempo al tiempo.
En mi pueblo dirían: Machete, estate en tu vaina. (Espera a que la cosa se ponga fea para sacarlo/usarlo)


In Spanish, there are some expressions that mean about the same as your individual meanings:
(1) ‘Dejar para mañana lo que puedes hacer hoy’
(2) 'Esperar a que pase la tormenta' or 'Esperar el golpe'.
One saying that encompasses both meanings may be non-existent

El primero que me viene a la cabeza es

Hasta el rabo, todo es toro

que de acuerdo al Instituto Cervantes significa

Procedente de la jerga taurina, advierte que nada debe considerarse
rematado hasta que no llegue su final. Por eso, no hay que confiarse
sino estar preparado para alguna sorpresa o imprevisto, como el torero
que piensa que el astado ya ha recibido bastante castigo cuando la
verdad es que puede revolverse inesperadamente y darle una cornada.

La frase que he resaltado en negrita se acomoda bastante bien al punto 1 de tu pregunta. Y descuidarte cuando estás toreando puede conllevar efectos no deseables, como indica tu punto 2.
Ante la insistencia de tac, he de aclarar que "hasta el rabo, todo es toro" NO se corresponde con la segunda acepción de "wait for the other shoe to drop", si la interpretamos como que uno tiene indicios (el primer zapato) de que algo malo va a ocurrirle inevitablemente (el segundo zapato) y está en un estado de espera ansiosa.
Aun así, me reitero en que SÍ cumple con la primera. "Hasta el rabo, todo es toro" indica que algo no ha terminado aún (el toro) y que hay que esperarse hasta que finalice completamente (pase el rabo) para iniciar otra acción. Hay un recomendación de espera implícita. Nada debe considerarse rematado hasta que no llegue su final. Espera a que finalice algo completamente y ya puedes comenzar otra cosa.


Demorar una acción hasta que otro asunto haya sido resuelto (o sea, una dependencia). 2. Esperar una consecuencia que es inevitable, generalmente negativa. Ninguna de las dos acepciones parece ajustarse mucho a tu frase.


@tac No entiendo qué quieres exactamente. No veo la dependencia de la que hablas en el idiom de los shoes. Lo mismo pasa con el del toro, te dice que esperes a que pase el toro completo antes de hacer lo que sea, a que termine lo que sea para hacer otra cosa. En inglés te dice que esperes al segundo zapato para hacer lo que sea. No esperarte puede conllevar consecuencias negativas, eso es lo único que he indicado del punto 2. No coincide lo de inevitable. Es muy dificil que dos frases hechas de idiomas distintos coincidan exactamente. Si tienes una mejor opción en argentino, bienvenida sea.

Es muy simple: esperar a que caiga el otro zapato tiene que ver con especular y esperar a que se resuelva una condición de la que la acción a hacer es fuertemente dependiente. Lo del toro es lo mismo que ‘dormirse en los laureles’, a lo que refiere es a no especular con resultados, que es justamente lo contrario de lo que está buscando el OP.

Es como ir ganando por un gol en un partido de fútbol. Si lo que esperás es que tu equipo siga jugando con ganas y que no den por sentado que van a ganar, decís ‘hasta el rabo todo es toro’; pero no ‘esperen a que caiga el otro zapato’, sería ridículo y significaría lo opuesto incluso.
